# Can I do conditional statements within Google Apps Script MailApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, conditional-statements

I thought it would be fairly simple, but I can't get conditional to work within MailApp. All I want to do is email an address created by a form and if there is an entry to "address2" to add that line. Without the conditional, most of the addresses will have a line break in the email. I want something similar to the code below, but Google Script won't let me save this because the if statement is throwing a syntax error.

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: "johndoe@gmail.com",
subject: "New Client",
htmlBody: "<p>New Client</p>" +
    "<p>Contact Name: " + ContactName + "<br>" +
    "Address:<br>" +
    "<br>" +
    address1 + "<br>" +
if(address2 !== 0)
    {address2 + "<br>" +}
    city + "," + state + zip "</p>".
});
```

Please advise. Tthank you.

Comment: Have you tried moving the conditional outside of the `MailApp` function, and use it to create an `address2` variable and then have that variable called in the `MailApp` function?  If there is no `address2`, then it doesn't end up in `MailApp`.

Comment: The conditional operator (aka ternary operator) is `?` with `:` i.e. `condition ? "true val" : "false val"`. It is often wise to wrap with parenthesis due to the low operator precedence of `?:` if writing a complex statement.

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to end up doing. I was able to pull of what I want with conditionals that use the entire MailApp blocks, so I'm going to end up with four MailApp blocks that's about 50 lines each (nested condition between international vs domestic). Thank you, @ron-kloberdanz!

Answer (score 0):

```
"<br>" + if(address2 !== 0) {address2 + "<br>" +} city + "," + state + zip "</p>"
```

is not valid JavaScript. An if-statement is not an operator that can be used in a formula; this is what the ternary operator `condition ? if_true : if_false` is for. Example:

```
"<br>" + (address2 !== 0 ? address2 + "<br>" : "") + city + "," + state + zip + "</p>"
```